# Upload attachment in corda

Tags: corda

I have tried to upload a attachment in corda. 
I have checked https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/release-M14. It is very complex and don't have a UI. When I tried to use some part of code it is showing full errors.
I have tried  https://github.com/corda/blacklist . But here hash is finding in HTML page. Can I get a simple example to upload a document using UI and hash finding in kt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blacklist sample [here](https://github.com/corda/samples) also has an example of uploading an attachment via RPC in Kotlin:

```
package net.corda.examples.attachments.client

import net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient
import net.corda.core.crypto.SecureHash
import net.corda.core.messaging.CordaRPCOps
import net.corda.core.utilities.NetworkHostAndPort.Companion.parse
import net.corda.core.utilities.loggerFor
import net.corda.examples.attachments.ATTACHMENT_EXPECTED_CONTENTS
import net.corda.examples.attachments.ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME
import net.corda.examples.attachments.BLACKLIST_JAR_PATH
import org.slf4j.Logger
import java.io.File
import java.util.jar.JarInputStream

/**
 * Uploads the jar of blacklisted counterparties with whom agreements cannot be struck to the node.
 */
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    UploadBlacklistClient().main(args)
}

private class UploadBlacklistClient {
    companion object {
        val logger: Logger = loggerFor<UploadBlacklistClient>()
    }

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        require(args.isNotEmpty()) { "Usage: uploadBlacklist <node address>" }
        args.forEach { arg ->
            val nodeAddress = parse(arg)
            val rpcConnection = CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress).start("user1", "test")
            val proxy = rpcConnection.proxy

            val attachmentHash = uploadAttachment(proxy, BLACKLIST_JAR_PATH)
            logger.info("Blacklist uploaded to node at $nodeAddress")

            val attachmentJar = downloadAttachment(proxy, attachmentHash)
            logger.info("Blacklist downloaded from node at $nodeAddress")

            checkAttachment(attachmentJar, ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME, ATTACHMENT_EXPECTED_CONTENTS)
            logger.info("Attachment contents checked on node at $nodeAddress")

            rpcConnection.notifyServerAndClose()
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Uploads the attachment at [attachmentPath] to the node.
 */
private fun uploadAttachment(proxy: CordaRPCOps, attachmentPath: String): SecureHash {
    val attachmentUploadInputStream = File(attachmentPath).inputStream()
    return proxy.uploadAttachment(attachmentUploadInputStream)
}

/**
 * Downloads the attachment with hash [attachmentHash] from the node.
 */
private fun downloadAttachment(proxy: CordaRPCOps, attachmentHash: SecureHash): JarInputStream {
    val attachmentDownloadInputStream = proxy.openAttachment(attachmentHash)
    return JarInputStream(attachmentDownloadInputStream)
}

/**
 * Checks the [expectedFileName] and [expectedContents] of the downloaded [attachmentJar].
 */
private fun checkAttachment(attachmentJar: JarInputStream, expectedFileName: String, expectedContents: List<String>) {
    var name = attachmentJar.nextEntry.name
    while (name != expectedFileName) {
        name = attachmentJar.nextEntry.name
    }

    val contents = attachmentJar.bufferedReader().readLines()

    if (contents != expectedContents) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Downloaded JAR did not have the expected contents.")
    }
}
```

Comment: How to run the program? 2018-06-27 09:14:01,331 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2018-06-27 09:14:01,336 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
[INFO ] 09:14:05,063 [main] (InternalUtils.kt:195) internal.RPCClient.logElapsedTime - Startup took 2840 msec {}
Exception in thread "main" ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]

Comment: I have run using Upload Blacklist. It is showing error

Comment: Are you running the nodes first?

Comment: When I tried to run the node, got message execution failed for task ':uploadBloacklist'

Comment: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers. Got message like this when I tried to run nodes.

Comment: How are you building the nodes?